# iOS Facebook sign in with AWS Federated Identities issues

Tags: ios, facebook, amazon-web-services, federated-identity

I am using AWS Cognito Federated ID with my iOS app for social providers (Facebook, Google). After sign in with Facebook, user is getting error '*Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool*'. If I allow unauthenticated ids in Fed IDs, then that user gets unauthenticated user ids (linked logins = 0) in Identity browser and gets session key etc. 
Can anyone help on resolving this issue?

Please don't mark this question as duplicated as I have seen all the similar questions and followed the solutions there, but to no avail!

Brief about code:

1. I have added Facebook in Authenticated Providers for Federated ID.
2. I have also added Facebook in Identity Providers for User Pool and done attributes mapping (mapped Id and Email).
3. I have created a social ID provider class which implements AWSIdentityProviderManager protocol. This class contains logins method as given:

   ```
   (AWSTask<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *> )logins {
       FBSDKAccessToken fbToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
       if(fbToken){
           NSString *token = fbToken.tokenString;
           return [AWSTask taskWithResult: @{ AWSIdentityProviderFacebook : token }];
       } else {
           NSLog(@"FB Token is not found in AWSSocialIdentityProvider class");
          return [AWSTask taskWithError:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"facebook"
          code:-1
          userInfo:@{@"error":@"No current Facebook access token"}]];
       }
   }
   ```
4. My Sign In View Controller does FB sign in. It creates fbCredentialsProvider by passing the socialIDProvider class as an identityProvider in it's construction, implemented as below:

   ```
   self.fbCredentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX" identityProviderManager:self.socialIDProvider];
   AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:self.fbCredentialsProvider];
   [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

   //wipe cached credentials
   [self.fbCredentialsProvider clearCredentials];
   ```

   //For calling fb logins
      [self.fbCredentialsProvider credentials];
5. The above code is called in didCompleteWithResult method of FB Login Button.
   That's it.

Comment: First of all, adding Facebook to Userpool (step 2) is not required if you use this code.

Comment: Are you using the correct IdentityPool id?

Comment: @Yes, I added the correct IdentityPoolId.